# Customise SearchView's symbols color

Tags: android, colors, searchview

G'day.
I'm trying to customise the searchview as I have a white toolbar with blue-ish text. When I go in "search mode" the text is visible, but the back arrow and the "X" are the same color as the background.

My code for the search item is:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

Then I change the searchView text and hint color using:

```
EditText searchEditText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
searchEditText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimary));
searchEditText.setHintTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.transparentBar));
```

How can I change the back and X icons?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32178669/3790150 try this

Comment: thanks @saeed. That helped for the clear button. I'm now working my way up to fix the other symbols (hopefully I'll find a way).