# How to preperly set clear button color in SearchView?

Tags: android, toolbar

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32178669/5154785) approach. However, the icon gets blurry on the device. Other answers I could find did not help.  Any help would be appreciated.
[image]

Code I am using:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            />


@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search);
    final SearchView searchView =  (SearchView) item.getActionView();


    ImageView searchCloseImage = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);
    searchCloseImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.close24);

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

My styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#009688</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#00796B </item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#4CAF50</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

Comment: `X` is looking good I think.

Comment: @meditat i double checked and compared to x icon on the apps, it really got blurred for some reason

Comment: have you used 5 different icons size for that @BekaBot

Comment: @Abhishekkumar no, I just uploaded the 24dp icon into drawable folder.

Comment: Have you uploaded all 5 images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this site to convert your image to different sizes : [romannurik.github.io](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=image&foreground.space.trim=0&foreground.space.pad=0&foreColor=rgb(0%2C%200%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(0%2C%200%2C%200)&crop=0&backgroundShape=none&effects=none&name=ic_launcher)

And add your images to Android studio `res` -> `mipmap` folder (one by one)
[image]

These are the different images size :

```
ldpi (low) ~120dpi
mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
hdpi (high) ~240dpi
xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi
```

Then set image from mipmap :

```
ImageView searchCloseImage = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);
searchCloseImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.close24);
```

Comment: Thank you. Another solution that worked for me is to apply vector drawable downloaded from this [source](https://materialdesignicons.com/)

Comment: Welcome , Happy to help you @BekaBot, Always use hdpi/mdpi... like images .